# Unordered list in HTML with animated list points

Tags: css, html5

I had this idea today, but I don't have any practical usage for it right now. Any feedback or improvements welcome.

Code is found at [CodePen](http://codepen.io/mizech/pen/wMwJRr), and also presented here as a snippet:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.point {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 50%;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.point:hover {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  color: #121212;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

li:nth-of-type(1) div:first-child {
  background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 1.0);
}

li:nth-of-type(2) div:first-child {
  background-color: rgba(60, 60, 60, 1.0);
}

li:nth-of-type(3) div:first-child {
  background-color: rgba(90, 90, 90, 1.0);
}

li:nth-of-type(4) div:first-child {
  background-color: rgba(120, 120, 120, 1.0);
}

li:nth-of-type(5) div:first-child {
  background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 1.0);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="point"></div>
    <div class="text">Alpha</div>
  </li>

  <li class="item">
    <div class="point"></div>
    <div class="text">Beta</div>
  </li>

  <li class="item">
    <div class="point"></div>
    <div class="text">Gamma</div>
  </li>

  <li class="item">
    <div class="point"></div>
    <div class="text">Delta</div>
  </li>

  <li class="item">
    <div class="point"></div>
    <div class="text">Epsilon</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HTML is far too overloaded.

- The `.point` elements are unnecessary and can be replaced by using the [pseudo-element `::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore). This requires adding the property `content: ""`.
- Generally as a rule, it's wrong to use the same class on all child elements, especially when it's generic like `item`. Better mark the list itself and use a child selector to select the items, for example `.animated-list > li`.
- The `<div class="text">` also seem unnecessary for this example. Setting `display: inline-block` and `width` have nothing to do with animated bullets and the `color` and `font-family` should be assigned on a higher level element such as the `body`.

In the CSS, as mentioned above

- replace `ul` with `ul.animated-list`
- replace `.item` with `ul.animated-list > li`
- replace `.point` with `ul.animated-list > li::before`

The sudden use of `:first-child` instead of `.point` seems strange. Use `ul.animated-list > li::before` here too, thus `ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(1)::before`.

Finally, I'd expect the the bullets to animate when hovering over the list item not just the bullet itself, so I'd replace `.point:hover` with `ul.animated-list > li:hover::before`.

And for some "flair" consider adding `transition: transform 0.1s;` to get a smooth animation.

EDIT: Here's my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adoWxp

Comment: Nice comprehensive list, + for reflection on the use of `:before`.

Comment: Instead of `:nth-of-type()`, just use `:nth-child()`. It may improve the performance of your selectors, since `:nth-child()` only selects the nth element, regardless of it's "type". Since this is an `<ul>`, I wouldn't expect anything else other than `<li>` inside it. Also, to speed up the selectors, you can use `.animated-list` instead of `ul.animated-list` and `.animated-list li` instead of `ul.animated-list > li`. Read more on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I think you misunderstand the problems with the child selector. `.animated-list li` is slower than `.animated-list > li`. If you don't want a child selector you need assign a class to all `li`, for example, `.animated-list__item` as suggested by [BEM](http://getbem.com/) and use that. I personally find `ul.animated-list > li` better. The performance problems are negligible and it is clearer, especially for a beginner.

Comment: Both the OP's and your solution has no list marker if adding more than 5 elements. Do you know if it's possible to work around that issue? Is is possible to set the color on first element, and let next elements have 90% on each color channel related to previous element, or something similar?

Comment: @holroy You could create a repeated pattern with `:nth-child()`: `:nth-child(5n+1)` for the 1st, 6th, 11th etc. item, `:nth-child(5n+2)` for the 2nd, 7th, 12th, etc. and so on.

Comment: @RoToRa, I've already done that in my answer here... My question is more if you know a way to reference the previous color, so that one could have only two style references. 1) for setting base color, and 2) for reducing the next items relative to previous item

Comment: @RoToRa Sorry, I missed that. I can't think of a way to do that with pure CSS. You have to use JavaScript or maybe use a CSS generator (for example, SASS or LESS) to create rules.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you wish to have your bullet points with the same color (but with different intensity), we could cut back a bit on the multiple definitions of `background-color` and just modify  `opacity` as such:

```
.point {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 0 50%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);

    transition: transform 0.6s; /* for smoother animation */
    background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 1.0); /* base color which we'll modify */
  }

  li:hover .point{
     transform: rotate(-45deg); 
   }

  li:nth-of-type(2) div:first-child  {
    opacity:0.8;
  }

  li:nth-of-type(3) div:first-child  {
    opacity:0.6;
  }

  li:nth-of-type(4) div:first-child {
    opacity:0.4;
  }

  li:nth-of-type(5) div:first-child {
    opacity:0.2;
  }
```

I've also added in a `transition` for `.point` for smoother animation. Normally users move their mouse over the text component of such lists not the bullet-item, so a slight addition to the `:hover` part will make your animation more apparent.

You're not doing any heavy lifting on your `li.item`s and even in the `nth-of-type` section you're just referring to the `li`s, so you could switch the `.item{}` to `ul > li{}` ( the `>` depicting direct children of the left-hand element). With that we can remove the `class="item"` definitions from the HTML reducing character output.

Misc note that depending on whether you'd want to use `.text` and `.point` in different contexts on your page, you might want to move related css definitions under the `ul` tag (same chain of thought applies for the `ul`, if you want all your `ul`s to look like this, then of course this is suffice, but if you wanted other kinds, you might want to add a class to this type of `ul`, eg. `ul.leaflist`).

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/u8vt5sqf/

Answer (score 2):

So far most of the solutions, including the solution by OP, will stop having list markers with more than 5 elements in the list, which is a show-stopper for me.

The ideal solution in my mind, would be to make the next color at a given percentage of previous color. But that requires programming, as far as I know. Another solution to make the list marker keep appearing is to extend the `nth-of-type`-selector using formulas, see [css-tricks.com :nth-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/).

This explains how you can write `:nth-of-type(an+b)`, where `a` represent the *repeat* factor, `n` is literal, `+` (or `-`) indicates addition/subtraction, and `b` is *offset*. In other words, if you use `5n+1` it denotes the 1st, 6th, 11th, ... elements, and `5n+2` denotes the 2nd, 7th, 8th, ... elements.

In the code below, based on RoToRa's answer, I've only changed the `:nth-of-type(...)` selectors into `:nth-of-type(5n+x)` (with `x` varying from 1 through 5. This repeats the formatting for every 5th element.

```css
ul.animated-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.animated-list > li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

ul.animated-list > li::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 50%;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

ul.animated-list > li:hover::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(5n+1)::before {
  background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 1.0);
}

ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(5n+2)::before  {
  background-color: rgba(60, 60, 60, 1.0);
}

ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(5n+3)::before {
  background-color: rgba(90, 90, 90, 1.0);
}

ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(5n+4)::before {
  background-color: rgba(120, 120, 120, 1.0);
}

ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(5n+5)::before {
  background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 1.0);
}
```

```html
<ul class="animated-list">
  <li>Alpha</li>
  <li>Beta</li>
  <li>Gamma</li>
  <li>Delta</li>
  <li>Epsilon</li>
  <li>Zeta</li>
  <li>Eta</li>
  <li>Theta</li>
  <li>Iota</li>
  <li>Kappa</li>
  <li>Lambda</li>
</ul>
```

If modifiying to include the opacity suggested by Gabor, one can use the concept of a base color, and with some slight justification to the base rotation, and implementation of the down-and-up scheme, one gets the following snippet:

```css
ul.animated-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.animated-list > li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

ul.animated-list > li::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 50%;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  transition: transform 0.1s;
  background-color: rgb(51, 166, 214); # Base color
}

ul.animated-list > li:hover::before {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

/* Not needed when doing opacity on background.color
 ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(8n+1)::before {
  background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 1.0);
} */

ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(8n+2)::before {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(8n+3)::before {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(8n+4)::before {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(8n+5)::before {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(8n+6)::before {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(8n+7)::before {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

ul.animated-list > li:nth-of-type(8n+8)::before {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<ul class="animated-list">
  <li>Alpha</li>
  <li>Beta</li>
  <li>Gamma</li>
  <li>Delta</li>
  <li>Epsilon</li>
  <li>Zeta</li>
  <li>Eta</li>
  <li>Theta</li>
  <li>Iota</li>
  <li>Kappa</li>
  <li>Lambda</li>
</ul>
```